# (linux) как распарсить строки в логе?

Tags: linux, консоль, grep, awk

Есть строки вида

Jul 6 17:35:10 sdc-prius motion_planner[1284]: new destination: [55.733510, 37.587401]

Jul 6 17:35:11 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.733668, 37.587143]

Jul 6 17:35:11 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 212, throttle: 420

Jul 6 17:35:11 sdc-prius control[1281]: steering: 145, throttle: 634

А надо какой-то линукс консольной командой превратить их в строки вида:

Jul 6 17:35:11 37.587143, 55.733668

Jul 6 17:35:13 37.586731, 55.733948

Jul 6 17:35:13 37.586744, 55.733955

Т.е. отбросить не нужное и поменять местами цифры.

Пробовал с помощью grep, awk, но без особых успехов.

Comment: Есть примеры команд которые Вы используете?

Comment: нужно еще и обновить время в логе ? (секунды разные)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно, что вы вообще хотите, в некоторых строках нет символов которые вы желаете видеть в выводе.
Для строк формата:
Jul 6 17:35:10 sdc-prius motion_planner[1284]: new destination: [55.733510, 37.587401]

Jul 6 17:35:11 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.733668, 37.587143] 
. где имеются все нужные данные, можно следующим способом поплясать:

```
awk ' {print $1,$2,$3,$9,$8} ' < file.txt | sed 's/\[/\ /' | sed 's/\,/\ /' | sed 's/\]/\ /'
```

, где file.txt - файл с Вашими строками.
При подаче на вход
 `Jul 6 17:35:10 sdc-prius motion_planner[1284]: new destination: [55.733510, 37.587401]
Jul 6 17:35:11 sdc-prius control[1284]: next waypoint: [55.733668, 37.587143]`

На выходе получаем - `Jul 6 17:35:10 37.587401   55.733510

Jul 6 17:35:11 37.587143   55.733668`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/\([a-z]* [0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\).*\[\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\), \([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\]/\1 \3 \2/Ip' имя_файла_с_логами.log
```